# How to know if python process is garbage collecting too often?

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection, pytorch

I am tuning the performance of a python job (that uses Pytorch and Nvidia Cuda).  My python process runs on a shared cluster where the max RAM needed must be explicitly specified. Since the lower is better, we tend to set lower RAM that doesn't cause Out of Memory.

In particular, I noticed that the RAM could make quite a difference on performance. For instance, if I set RAM=6GB, my job takes 27Hours. If I set max RAM=10GB (keeping all other variables same), the same job takes about ~16Hrs. Most of the work is done on GPU using GPU RAM, so the CPU and  CPU RAM is only for housekeeping and moving tensors.

My suspect is garbage collector runs too often when I set less RAM. I had observed this kind of behavior when I was dealing with JavaVM, [and I had tools to inspect how much time my JVM process spends in the garbage collector](https://visualvm.github.io/).

However, with python, I am clueless.

**Are there any ways to inspect the memory management, in particular, Garbage Collector time (fraction of runtime)?**

Comment: CPython uses reference counting for it's memory management. Unless you have reference cycles (in which case, we would have to examine a [mcve]) objects are reclaimed deterministically *as soon as their reference count reaches 0*. Now, there is a cyclic garbage collector (that is controllable via the `gc` module). It may or may not be safe to simply turn that off, and at the very least, it will let you see if it is having an effect on the timing.

Comment: great!, thanks for the link to "minimal, complete, verifiable example " I will try to get that one